# gwt - how to find a locale is bidi in client package - using dynamic i18n

Tags: java, gwt

I am using dynamic string i18n in gwt. For supporting BIDI, i need to know if the locale is RTL or not.

I cannot use

```
LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale()
```

because it will not return the locale value in my case. 
Is there a way in GWT to find out if the locale is RTL

Answer (score 0):

If `LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().isRTL()` can't be used and you don't know the current locale (by string representation, at least), you can't know if it is RTL.

If you *do* have a string representation of the locale in question, you can use [`GwtLocaleFactory.fromString(...)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/GwtLocaleFactory.html#fromString%28java.lang.String%29).

Just out of curiosity though, why exactly won't `LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale()` return the locale? Is there an error of some sort?